# Jooq & R2DBC execute DDL

Tags: jooq, r2dbc

I have my tables schema generated from the database, I'm trying to execute the ddl to create the tables using an r2dbc connection to an h2 in memory, but I cannot figure out what should I do.

The `DSLContext.ddl` method returns a `Queries` object that is not a `Publisher` and I cannot find any way to execute those queries with a `Publisher` but only doing a `.block()` method that is failing because r2dbc doesn't allow for blocking calls.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems DDL with R2DBC have weird issues in JOOQ, the only way I found to make it work across different databases (MySQL, H2) is, execute the raw SQL of the DDL manually with:

```java
    public static void initDB(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        var dsl = DSL.using(connectionFactory);
        Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
            .flatMapMany(conn -> Flux.fromIterable(dsl.ddl(MySchema.MY_SCHEMA))
                .flatMap(query -> conn.createStatement(query.getSQL()).execute(), 1)
            )
            .blockLast();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending feature request [#12207](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12207) to let [`Queries`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Queries.html) extend `Publisher<Integer>` for convenience. It might not be implemented, though. There's no obvious choice between:

- Executing the queries as a [`Batch`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Batch.html)
- Executing the queries one-by-one
- Executing the queries as a [`Block`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Block.html)

There are probably preferenes,  but not necessarily a strict winner. Turning a `Queries` object into a `Batch` can already be done using [`DSLContext.batch(Queries)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batch(org.jooq.Queries)), and starting with jOOQ 3.18 and [#14708](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14708), also with `Queries.batch()`. `Batch` is already a `Publisher<Integer>`.

Alternatively, you can obviously do this:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(queries);
```

Comment: Solved using the `Batch` solution, `Flux.fromIterable(queries);` seems to not be feasiable as it then the single `Query` is not a `Publisher` and its `execute*` methods cannot be invoked as using r2dbc they are failing because blocking operations

Comment: Nope seems the batch solution doesn't work with H2 db :\

Comment: @rascio: Well, if you have a minimal reproducer, you could report it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose